# Is there Java/SSJS equivalent of @AttachmentModifiedTimes?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I want to show list of attachments and FileDownload control is not an option (need custom actions for every file).

To get name and size of attachments there are properties of `EmbeddedObject`. AFAIK, to get modified time of attachment there is only one option: to use pure @Formula, either via `session.evaluate` or view containing column with @AttachmentModifiedTimes.

Is there a way (Java/SSJS) to get attachment's modified (and created) time without native @Formulas? That means date stored with file shown in document properties for $FILE item.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a Repeat Control to the page and bind that to the attachments (stored in a rich text field) using document1.getAttachmentList("rt_field_name"). Every item in that list is an object of class

```
com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument$AttachmentValueHolder
```

That class has a **getLastModified()** method that returns the last modified time as a Double.

A couldn't find a reference on the web showing the full API, but if you use the API Inspector in the XPage Debug Toolbar (sorry for the shameless plug...) you can view all properties and methods using:

getComponent( 'id_of_repeat_control' ).getDataModel().getRowData()

**UPDATE**

Found the API [here](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/XPagesExtAPI/8.5.2/com/ibm/xsp/model/domino/wrapped/DominoDocument.AttachmentValueHolder.html),

Comment: just a reminder: getLastModified() returns long so here's the way to show it on XP: new java.util.Date(row.getLastModified())

Comment: d'oh: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO61249 it seems the API is broken and that is stated as "permanent restriction". no comment...

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you want to achieve. 
In general you can use @AttachmentModifiedTimes() - as well as @AttachmentNames() - as SSJS.

Comment: You can't point these @Formulas at different DDS, they work with current = last defined data source, AFAIK.

Comment: Probably you are right - I just tested this once with one simple datasource and it kind of worked. Thanks for the feedback though.