# compute dynamically the allowDelete property of file download xpages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am using a file download control and I would like to set the value of the "allowDelete" property dynamically depending on whether the document is in edit or read mode. However, this
property is computed onload of the page. I tried calling the function "setAllowDelete(boolean)" on the onclick event of a button or the "beforeRenderResponse" event of a custom control and a partial or full update to change the value of the property, but it didn't change.

Do you know if there is a way to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem. There are two options to workaround it.

1) To use two controls, one with deletion enabled, the other with deletion disabled, and use rendered properties according to edit state (or user role).

2) Render download controls by your own, as data table or repeat. However, this solution has [its own problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570624/is-there-java-ssjs-equivalent-of-attachmentmodifiedtimes), too.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! Could you please explain a little bit more the second option?

Comment: In the question I have linked is link to API documentation http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/XPagesExtAPI/8.5.2/com/ibm/xsp/model/domino/wrapped/DominoDocument.AttachmentValueHolder.html. From there you can call getAttachmentList() method and feed it into dataTable or repeat. Rows will render attributes based on FileRowData methods. At docuemnt data source level you will call removeAttachment() method to remove attachment from document.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand now what you mean. However, I tried the first option a little bit differently. I added two panels with two file downloads and render only one whether the document is in edit mode or in read mode. It seems that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just calculating the property like this?

```
<xp:fileDownload .... >
    <xp:this.allowDelete><![CDATA[${javascript:
        return document.isEditable()}]]>
    </xp:this.allowDelete>
</xp:fileDownload>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I have tried this. The thing is that I have a repeat control with documents and when I click to a document, I open a custom control that contains the file download. This is done with partial refreshes, so the xpage loads only in the beginning. The above code computes only onload due to the $. I would like to replace the $ with # to make it compute dynamically but it doesn't allow me.