# Why is my fileDownload control showing the trashcan even in read mode?

Tags: xpages

This is a rather strange one I think, and I'm sure I made a mistake here myself:

in one of my applications I'm showing a fileDownload control bound to a Richtext field in my underlying NotesDocument. The control's properties a are set to *Hide if no attachments*, show *size*, *type* and *created* as well as *allow delete*. The control itself sits inside a custom control, being part of another custom control, similar to this:

Xpage.xsp
 - ccContainer
 - - ccInnerDoc

Document datasources for both the container and the "inner" doc are defined at the root of ccContainer and passed into the inner doc.
The inner doc's datasource is comnputed based on a document selection, and it's igenoreRequestParams property is set to **false** so that I can display the contents of the selected datasource in a given panel etc.

The selected doc is first opened in read mode, and I can set it to edit mode using a button.

Problem now is that my file download control **always** is showing the delete icon (trashcan) no matter which mode the doc is opened in. And it's not only the icon showing, it also pretends to work by asking me whether I really want to delete and then really removes the file attachment. Only that this change of course cannot be stored into the datasource because it's only open in read mode.

I'm sure that this behaviour is some side-effect of something else in my application (to a certain extent I rebuilt this in a plain new db and until now cannot reproduce it), but I'm at the end of my knowledge of what this could be.

Any hint of what could be causing this is more than welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746894/compute-dynamically-the-allowdelete-property-of-file-download-xpages

Comment: great stuff, of course. Thanks once again ;) - maybe you want to include the link as an answer so that I can close my question more easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of @Frantisek Kossuth I answer this myself: see [compute dynamically the allowDelete property of file download xpages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746894/compute-dynamically-the-allowdelete-property-of-file-download-xpages)

Thanks again, Frantisek!